# Chainlink Node: unable to lock ORM: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5432: connect: connection refused logger/default.go:155 stacktrace=gith

Tags: orm, chainlink

IM having a issue 2021-01-03T05:30:44Z [ERROR] unable to lock ORM: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5432: connect: connection refused logger/default.go:155 stacktrace=gith ub.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/logger.Errorf

this is what my .env looks like

```
ROOT=/chainlink
LOG_LEVEL=debug
ETH_CHAIN_ID=1
CHAINLINK_TLS_PORT=0
SECURE_COOKIES=false
GAS_UPDATER_ENABLED=true
ALLOW_ORIGINS=*
ETH_URL=wss://main-rpc.linkpool.io/ws
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://:@0.110.208.7:432/
```

And yes I am a noob when it comes to programing but I sure do enjoy learning it!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your environment variable to .bashrc, then source .bashrc && set

```
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://:@0.110.208.7:432/
```

Once set you can then do :

chainlink node start